# Can I re-use AutoNumber value during INSERT to populate another field? C# & Access Database

Tags: c#, database

I have a table with `componentID(AutoNumber)` and `componentCode(string)` which is a combination of prefix letter and componendID. I want to get the `componentID` and add prefix and write it to `componentCode`.

```
ie;
ComponentID: 123, ComponentCode: 10PT0123.
ComponentID: 124, ComponentCode: 10PT0124.
etc.
```

What will be the simplest way to do this with c#/access database? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eureka! I'm not sure if it's the simplest or the most elegant solution but works for me :)

```
        OleDbConnection cnJetDB = new OleDbConnection(strDB);

        OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand();
        cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO tableComponents (ComponentDesc) VALUES (@ComponentDesc)";
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ComponentDesc", partDesc);

        cnJetDB.Open();

        cmd.Connection = cnJetDB;
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

        cmd.CommandText = "SELECT @@IDENTITY";
        int newID = (int)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
        MessageBox.Show(newID.ToString());

        OleDbCommand cmd2 = new OleDbCommand();
        cmd2.CommandText = "UPDATE tableComponents SET ComponentCode=@CompCode WHERE ComponentID="+newID;
        cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CompCode", "PREFIX" + newID.ToString());

        cmd2.Connection = cnJetDB;
        cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery();

        cnJetDB.Close();
```

Comment: I think you have to avoid opening a new connection between `INSERT` and `@@IDENTITY`.  Oh wait, you did.  But then you opened a gratuitous new connection before the `UPDATE`.  And made a new command variable.  Not sure what advantage that would have.

Comment: Also, I would do `UPDATE t SET ComponentCode=@Prefix+ComponentID WHERE ComponentID=@ID` and let the database do the concatenation.  Can't really give a strong rationale, though.

Comment: Thanks Ben, I've got rid of the new connection before update, looks better now.